# How to create a Agile burn-up chart in Excel

Tags: excel, agile, agile-project-management, excel-template

Does anyone know of free Agile burn-up chart templates in excel or how to create a burn-up chart in excel?  I find a lot of burn-down charts, but can't find instructions or templates for burn-up charts.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quickie burn up I just created in Google Docs. You should be able to use this as a foundation for creating your own. Hope it helps.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuPj0DNF9GoHdElURXZpdnZheXpQdGE4MnI0Wm8zaVE

Thanks!

Brandon

Comment: No problem. Is that what you were looking for?